# Convert read-only character array to float without null termination in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm looking for a C function like the following that parses a length-terminated char array that expresses a floating point value and returns that value as a float.

```
float convert_carray_to_float( char const * inchars, int incharslen ) {
 ...
}
```

### Constraints:

1. The character at `inchars[incharslen]` might be a digit or other character that might confuse the commonly used standard conversion routines.
2. The routine is not allowed to invoke `inchars[incharslen] = 0` to create a z terminated string in place and then use the typical library routines.  Even patching up the z-overwritten character before returning is not allowed.
3. Obviously one could copy the char array in to a new writable char array and append a null at the end, but I am hoping to avoid copying.  My concern here is performance.

This will be called often so I'd like this to be as efficient as possible. I'd be happy to write my own routine that parses and builds up the float, but if that's the best solution, I'd be interested in the most efficient way to do this in C.

If you think removing constraint 3 really is the way to go to achieve high performance, please explain why and provide a sample that you think will perform better than solutions that maintain constraint 3.

Comment: So given (1), how can it be a valid number?

Comment: I think the performance *"loss"* caused by copying the array will be negligible if you think of how hard it would be to convert the array to a `float` without using the library functions efficiently.

Comment: if the length is known at compile time you could use     sscanf(string,"%Xf",&f); with X == incharslen. Not sure of the performance though

Comment: Drop requirement #3 - it is premature optimization. `{ char buf[incharslen+1]; memcpy(buf,inchars, incharslen); buf[incharslen] = 0; return atof(buf); }`

Comment: I agree with @chux. Don't assume that copying the string will harm performance unacceptably. Even if the function is called many times, it will be called most of the time on very short strings, yes? That's a cheap copy. Measure performance first to find out where the bottlenecks are, and then figure out how to optimize that code.

Comment: Eugene, please assume this is a large block of memory with many items packed in it.   For example 2.0 and 4.0 could be packed together as 2.04.0 in memory.

Comment: Will they be in standard format like `-1.234` or could there be notation like `1.23e+004`?

Comment: @user3624334: So given `const char inchars[6] = "2.04.0";`, the client will call `convert_carray_to_float(inchars, 3)` followed by `onvert_carray_to_float(incharsi+3, 3)`, right? Otherwise there's no way to tell where the first number ends and the second begins.

Comment: @chux: `atof()` does no error checking.

Comment: @Keith Thompson True that `atof()` is not specified to set any error flags should it detect problems.  `strtod()` is a good alternative yet it needs a fair amount of additional code around it to detect overflow,  (underflow,) and no conversion.  Those issues seem secondary to OP prime concern.

Comment: IMO there is no significant performance impact copying candidate `char` arrays into a string for `float` conversion vs. the correctness and maintenance issues with rolling ones own `char_array_to_float()`.  OTOH there is one concern that makes sense, depending on platform, `double` may be much slower than `float` and using STL `strtod()` could be slow vs `OP_char_array_to_float()`.  Again, copying the array is not the bottleneck.

Comment: @chux: The behavior of `atof("1.0e99999")` is actually undefined, assuming that value can't be represented ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.22.1). I think the behavior of `atof("NOPE")` is also undefined, though the standard is less explicit on this point than I'd like it to be. That might be acceptable if you're willing to assume that the input is sufficiently well formed.

Comment: I've tested chux's routine.  It's true that the copy there only adds about 15% to the execution time over the time of just atof if the string were known to be more compatible with the std routine. ((more comments about further discoveries in a few minutes.))

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  The two answers below and the discussion above all have fueled experimenting on my part.  I'm disappointed that there isn't a little known routine that I was overlooking, but the hand-written code I've written is giving me very good results now.  Thx to everyone.  I hope future readers find this discussion helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty good outline.

Not sure it covers all cases, but it shows most of the flow:

```
float convert_carray_to_float(char const * inchars, int incharslen)
{
    int Sign = +1;
    int IntegerPart = 0;
    int DecimalPart = 0;
    int Denominator = 1;
    bool beforeDecimal = true;

    if (incharslen == 0)
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }

    int i=0;
    if (inchars[0] == '-')
    {
        Sign = -1;
        i++;
    }
    if (inchars[0] == '+')
    {
        Sign = +1;
        i++;
    }

    for( ; i<incharslen; ++i)
    {
        if (inchars[i] == '.')
        {
            beforeDecimal = false;
            continue;
        }

        if (!isdigit(inchars[i]))
        {
            return 0.0f;
        }

        if (beforeDecimal)
        {
            IntegerPart = 10 * IntegerPart + (inchars[i] - '0');
        }
        else
        {
            DecimalPart = 10 * DecimalPart + (inchars[i] - '0');
            Denominator *= 10;
        }
    }

    return Sign * (IntegerPart + ((float)DecimalPart / Denominator));
}
```

Comment: Minor: Suggest `else if (inchars[i] == '+')` to detect bad input like "-+123".

Comment: I've built a similar routine in order to compare approaches.   Mine has a bit more checking and handles more situations, but it doesn't have all the overflow and underflow checks that David Gay's code has and that atof() probably has.   It also appears to perform about 3x faster than atof().  And even faster if optimizations are turned on.   The fact that it doesn't copy the source characters definitely helps, but I think the bigger win is probably the absence of those underflow and overflow checks. -- So I think for some situations this approach of "rolling your own" could be winning.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

David Gay's implementation, used in the *BSD libcs, can be found here: https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/contrib/gdtoa/ The most important file is strtod.c, but it requires some of the headers and utilities. Modifying that to check the termination every time the string pointer is updated would be a bit of work but not awful.

However, you might afterwards think that the cost of the extra checks is comparable to the cost of copying the string to a temporary buffer of known length, particularly if the strings are short and of a known length, as in your example of a buffer packed with 3-byte undelimited numbers. On most architectures, if the numbers are no more than 8 bytes long and you were careful to ensure that the buffer had a bit of tail room, you could do the copy with a single 8-byte unaligned memory access at very little cost.